# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \cos\left(2x\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{4}}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was hoping for some guidance on how to approach the following limit, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \cos\left(2x\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{4}}}$

Now for context, I already know that the answer is $0$, but I'm trying to  be more formal in how I prove it. The way I have been approaching this is to first convert it into a combination of exponentials and logarithms, which obtains $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \exp\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\ln\left(\cos2x\right)\right)$ However, the problem with this is that we eventually see that the term inside the logarithm basically goes to 0, and thus the term inside the exponential goes to $-\infty$, because of that, I don't believe this step is completely legitimate, especially as I move the limit in and out of the function later on and apply L'Hopital's rule.

So how can one rigorously handle this process? If I play it fast and loose, I can just go through with that step, bring the limit inside of the exponential, apply L'Hopital, take out the $\frac{\sin2x}{2x}$ that pops up (since it equals $1$), plug $0$ into the cosine term, and be left with $e^{\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\left(-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)}}$. If I naively take the limit back out, I can use a very straightforward $\epsilon-\delta$ proof to show that the whole limit equals $0$. But again, this is the result of having essentially taken the logarithm of $0$ in that earlier step, so I don't think it's legitimate.

So, in essence, how can I either navigate around this divergent limit that pops up, or how can I more rigorously approach it if it does. It's been a while since I took real analysis, so I'm kind of shaky on this.

Many thanks!

Comment: This answers your question: [Please calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275944/please-calculate-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-ln-cos-xx2). It tells you that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(\cos (2x)}{x^2}=-2$ hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(\cos (2x)}{x^4}=-\infty$, so that $\lim_{x \to 0} \cos\left(2x\right)^{\frac{1}{x^{4}}}=\lim_{y\to-\infty}e^y=0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval That's a good link you gave, but in this case, I hope my answer is much straightforward. Of course it all depends upon the one who posted, which makes his/her more comfortable.

Comment: @ThomasFinley Your answer does not follow the OP's attempt but is more efficient indeed. It looks very much like a duplicate, though.

Comment: None of them was mine. Meanwhile, I found this duplicate: [Removing $1^{\infty}$ indeterminacy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075794).

Comment: All his comments are gone...

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. The issue/question I am having is this: by what process can I bring the limit inside of the exponential in the first place? My understanding of limits of compositions (i.e. the limit of f[g(x)]) is that the limit operand can only be brought inside if the limit of g exists. However, in this case, the limit of g does not exist, because it goes to $-\infty$. The exponential is well defined in this case, but the inside is not.

Comment: This is by "composition of limits".  It applies as well to infinite limits, which *do* "exist" (and the proof is the same). If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=-\infty$ then $\lim_{x\to a}e^{f(x)}=\lim_{y\to-\infty}e^y=0.$

Comment: Ah I think I see. So the only requirement with limits of compositions is that the outside function be continuous at the limit of the inside, and not that the inside limit actually exists? (I understand all of this on an intuitive level, but I've just been concerned that I'm not being formal enough.)

Comment: No, the inside limit has to exist, but in $[-\infty,+\infty]$ (infinities included). And in the case of such infinite limits of the "inside function", continuity of the "outside function"  is off topic. You cannot say that $\exp$ is continuous at $-\infty,$ but only that its limit at $-\infty$ is $0.$